# Error with gradle when adding google maps

Tags: java, android, gradle

Thats my gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "icon1.0"
}
buildTypes {


        debug {
            resValue "string", "google_maps_api_key", "xxx"
        }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':pullToRefreshLib')
    compile files('libs/android-async-http.jar')
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')
    compile files('libs/bcprov.jar')
    compile files('libs/uicandroid.jar')
    compile files('libs/worklight-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile project(':aFileChooser')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.1.jar')
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

My project build when removing the map 
but after adding I have this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

Does anyone know what is wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Edit :

After executing gradle -q dependencies

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Project :app
------------------------------------------------------------

_debugAndroidTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugAndroidTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :pullToRefreshLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- project :aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
     |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
     |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)

_debugCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :pullToRefreshLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- project :aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
     |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
     |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)

_debugUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_debugUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :pullToRefreshLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- project :aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
     |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
     |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)

_releaseCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
+--- project :pullToRefreshLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- project :aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
     |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
     |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)

_releaseUnitTestApk - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

_releaseUnitTestCompile - ## Internal use, do not manually configure ##
No dependencies

androidJacocoAgent - The Jacoco agent to use to get coverage data.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidJacocoAnt - The Jacoco ant tasks to use to get execute Gradle tasks.
\--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.ant:0.7.4.201502262128
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.report:0.7.4.201502262128
     |    +--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.7.4.201502262128 (*)
     |    \--- org.ow2.asm:asm-debug-all:5.0.1
     \--- org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:0.7.4.201502262128

androidTestApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'androidTest' classes.
No dependencies

androidTestCompile - Classpath for compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestProvided - Classpath for only compiling the androidTest sources.
No dependencies

androidTestWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'androidTest'.
No dependencies

apk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'main' classes.
No dependencies

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- project :pullToRefreshLib
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1
|         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1
+--- project :aFileChooser
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.5
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
|    \--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1 (*)
\--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appinvite:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:22.2.0
     |         \--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0 -> 23.1.1 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0
     |         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0
     |              \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0
     |         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-panorama:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:8.3.0
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wallet:8.3.0
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)
     |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0 (*)
     |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0 (*)
     \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:8.3.0
          \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.3.0 (*)

debugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'debug' classes.
No dependencies

debugCompile - Classpath for compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the debug sources.
No dependencies

debugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'debug'.
No dependencies

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
No dependencies

default-mapping - Configuration for default mapping artifacts.
No dependencies

provided - Classpath for only compiling the main sources.
No dependencies

releaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'release' classes.
No dependencies

releaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the release sources.
No dependencies

releaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'release'.
No dependencies

testApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'test' classes.
No dependencies

testCompile - Classpath for compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testDebugApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testDebug' classes.
No dependencies

testDebugCompile - Classpath for compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testDebug sources.
No dependencies

testDebugWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testDebug'.
No dependencies

testProvided - Classpath for only compiling the test sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseApk - Classpath packaged with the compiled 'testRelease' classes.
No dependencies

testReleaseCompile - Classpath for compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseProvided - Classpath for only compiling the testRelease sources.
No dependencies

testReleaseWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'testRelease'.
No dependencies

testWearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'test'.
No dependencies

wearApp - Link to a wear app to embed for object 'main'.
No dependencies
```

any one see errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google's document [Setting Up Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Note: If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

You might want to replace this line in your build.gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

To

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

So that the project only include the maps module you need instead of the whole play service library group.

Let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known issue called the 65K problem, it causes an OutOfMemory exception. [Click here for more information about the problem.](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

To solve the problem, you should firstly add the multidex support library in your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
```

Then you should follow these three simple steps to make it work:

If you’re not implementing an Application class yourself, you can simply define the library’s MultiDexApplication in your Android Manifest file under the application tag:

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

If you are implementing your own Application class, you can either simply override the MultiDexApplication file:

```
public class MyAwesomeApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
```

Or if your application class is already extending another class, you can just override attachBaseContext method and add the following call to it:

```
@Override protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) { super.attachBaseContext(context); Multidex.install(this); }
```

Hope this helps you. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when I get this error message, I'd just clean the project and everything would be fine.

Just in case it happened because there were duplicated dex files in the library.

Could you run `gradle -q dependencies` in the command line under you path of your application (projectRoot/app) and paste the result here please?

Comment: You need to install gradle.